# Binomial Series Expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

After working out binomial expansion of $\frac{1-x}{10}$ to power of $-3$ for my homework, I have to determine the value of $\frac{1}{0.999}$ to power of $3$ correct to $14$ decimal places. We haven't done it in lessons yet and the textbook doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where do you stuck when you apply the binomial theorem ?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\verts{x} < 10}$:

\begin{align}
\pars{1 - {x \over 10}}^{-3} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-3 \choose n}\pars{-\,{x \over 10}}^{n} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{n + 2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
\bracks{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 10^{n}}x^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1} \over 2 \times 10^{n}}\,x^{n}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\pars{1 \over 0.999}^{3} & = 0.999^{\,-3} = \pars{1 - 0.001}^{-3} =
\pars{1 - {0.01 \over 10}}^{-3} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1} \over 2 \times 10^{n}}\,\pars{0.01}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1} \over 2 \times 1000^{n}}
\end{align}

---

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\color{#f00}{N}}
{\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1} \over 2 \times 1000^{n}}\qquad \implies \qquad
\begin{array}{cl}\hline
\ds{\color{#f00}{N}} & \ds{\color{#f00}{\phantom{123456}value}}
\\
\ds{0} & \ds{1}
\\
\ds{1} & \ds{1.003}
\\
\ds{2} & \ds{1.0030059999999998}
\\
\ds{3} & \ds{1.0030060099999998}
\\
\ds{4} & \ds{1.0030060100149998}
\\
\ds{\large 5} & \ds{\color{#f00}{1.00300601001502}09}
\\
\ds{6} & \ds{\color{#f00}{1.00300601001502}09}
\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$